# import "unittest2" could not be resolved Pylance

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, python-unittest, pylance

I'm getting this error in my **Python code for raspberry pi.**

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import warnings
import time
from threading import Timer
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
if sys.version[:3] == '2.6':
    import unittest2 as unittest
else:
    import unittest
```

Comment: Looks like pylance cannot handle the conditional import. If you cannot remove that import, and don't find another another solution, you could install `unittest2` as a workaround, even if it is not needed.

Comment: Do you really need to support Python 2.6? Is that even installed on your rpi?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes I've installed unittest2.

Comment: @OneCricketeer  yes I've python 2.7 installed in my RPi

Comment: If you have 2.7, then you dont need the `sys.version[:3] == '2.6':` check or the following line, so simply remove `import unittest2 as unittest`